# Наложение блоков друг на друга

Tags: html, css

На странице есть блок, который залезает под верхний блок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. красный налезает под черный.

Как это было сделано: у красного блока `position: relative`, `top: -50px` и `z-index: -1`. Теперь необходимо на красном блоке разместить кнопки, ссылки. Но т.к. у красного блока `z-index: -1`, то кнопки не нажимаются.

P.S. Красный обязательно должен быть фоном, а не картинкой. И кнопки должны располагаться внутри этого блока.

Comment: Добавьте код или ссылку на сайт, так будет проще и правильный ответ получите быстрее)

Comment: Проблема тут с реализацией. В том, что нижний блок вообще налезает на верхний когда есть псевдоэлементы и бордеры

Answer (score 1):

z-index здесь вообще не нужен - он лишний. Просто position: relative и top: -50px. А затем красному блоку присваиваем position: absolute и уже позиционируем, как нужно.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  position: relative;
  top:-50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.red button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.red a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 85px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.red a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="red">
  <button>OK</button>
  <a href="https://www.tut.by/">www.tut.by</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Как я понял, у вас немного по другому. Для лучшего представления, красное это слайдер(с кнопками, ссылками), а черное это шапка которая немного налезает на слайдер

Comment: "Вот черное и должно быть спозиционировано абсолютно с положительным z-индексом, а красное не надо трогать." (с) Стендаль.

Answer (score 1):

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="stule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="red">
       <div class="black">
          <button>OK</button>
          <a href="https://www.rambler.ru/">www.rambler.ru</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

stule.css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.black {
  position: absolute;   
  background-color: black; 
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.red button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.red a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 85px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.red a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```